# Create object of javascript file in typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, typescript

I have javascript file adal.js in Scripts folder.

I have separate Services folder into which my typescript(ts) files are there.One of my typescript file wants to use functions and variables from adal.js.

It is as follows:-

```
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

//import 'expose-loader?AuthenticationContext!../../../node_modules/adal-angular/lib/adal.js';
import 'expose-loader?AuthenticationContext!../Scripts/adal.js'; 

let createAuthContextFn: adal.AuthenticationContextStatic = AuthenticationContext;

@Injectable()

export class AdalService {

    private context: adal.AuthenticationContext;

    constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {

        this.context = new createAuthContextFn(configService.getAdalConfig);

    }
```

But it is giving me error :-

Can not find namespace adal.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT 1:-**

I dont have src folder I directly have typings folder as below :-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it to your global type definitions. If you're using Angular CLI, this is in the `src/typings.d.ts` file. You can add the following:

```
declare module 'adal'
```

Then import it as

```
import * as adal from '../Scripts/adal.js'
```

Comment: I need to do this in typings folder? Please see my edit1